# Attractive Fixed -Point

Tags: real-analysis

How can you (easily) determine if the unique fixed point of the following function is attractive? I have my own way in which I don`t use inequalities or derivatives but only use algebra. I wonder if you have a faster, easier way.

1. $f(x) = 1-x^2$    in $[0,1]$   , not attractive
2. $g(x) = 1+\sqrt{x}$   in $[0,4]$ , attractive

My method applies to monotonic function. It tests if the double composition $f(f(x))$ has only one or more fixed points.

Comment: umm.. so what does your method say when you pick $f(x) = x/2$ or $f(x)=2x$ ?

Comment: It must be assumed that f transforms $[a,b]$ into itself. For the first function you may take $[0,1]$ and you get an attracted fixed-point 0. I will not apply my method for 2x since I don't have a suitable interval.

Comment: It must be assumed that f transforms $[a,b]$ into itself. For the first function you may take $[0,1]$ and get an attracted fixed-point $0$. I may not apply my method for $2x$ since there is no suitable interval for that.